# How do I start an intent without the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in an Android service?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am trying to connect to different activities from a custom soft keyboard. I need the activity underneath the keyboard to allow data to be sent without the activity creating a new instance of itself. For example: if the keyboard is over the messaging application, I want to send that application data without losing the current conversation that the user is typing into. I currently have the following code to send data to the activity.

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
  //sendIntent.putExtra("thread_id", (long) 1);
  sendIntent.setType("image/*"); 
  startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I am getting the following obvious error when I try to run it...

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6129): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

How can I keep the current activity underneath the keyboard from resetting itself when an intent is sent from the keyboard service? Or more simply, how can I send an intent from a service without setting the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this like that. A `Service` can't pass data to an `Activity` without "starting it". You don't want to do that. You want to pass data to an "already started" `Activity`. There's 2 ways to do this:

1. Use a bound `Service`. Have the `Activity` bind to the `Service`. The `Activity` can then call methods on the`Service` (using AIDL) and receive returned data.
2. Use a `BroadcastReceiver`. Have the `Activity` create and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the returned data. In your `Service`, send a broadcast `Intent` when you want to transmit data to the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by several ways but you must set flag in order to complete task.

If you want to create a new instance and close the current instance you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

If you want to reuse the same instance of the activity in this case you need to set both `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`after that it will not create another instance of the activity but call `onNewIntent()` of activity to run the new Intent.

Comment: This should work in most cases, but seems to fall short when using an Android service. The question was a bit vague, take a look at the revisions